# extracting data from panda series as per the index of another panda series

Tags: python, pandas

There are three panda series

```
x = pd.Series([220,340,500,600,700,900,540,60])
y = pd.Series([2,1,2,2,1])
z = pd.Series([])
```

Each element of y will denote how many elements to add and to be put into z
example : if series has 2 in the start, then i will add first two elements at the start 220 and 340 to get 560 and then put it in z as its first element. Next I have 1 in y that means i will take 500 from x (third element) and put it in z as its second element and so on

Here is what I have tried

```
j = 0
for i in y:
    par = y[i]
    z[i] = x[j:par + j].sum()
    j = j+par
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groupby y's index repeated:

```
x.groupby(y.index.repeat(y)).sum()

0     560
1     500
2    1300
3    1440
4      60
dtype: int64
```

---

If the length mismatches, this will lead to a `ValueError`. In that case, a safer alternative is to groupby the cumsum, repeated, and reset the index:

```
x.groupby(y.cumsum().repeat(y).reset_index(drop=True)).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```
df = x.to_frame(name='x').reset_index(drop=True)
df['cat'] = pd.cut(df.index+1, y.cumsum(), labels=False)
df['cat'] = df['cat'].fillna(-1).add(1)

z = df.groupby('cat').x.sum()
```

Out:

```
cat
0.0     560
1.0     500
2.0    1300
3.0    1440
4.0      60
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the index conflict issue, just update your loop to use a range instead

```
j = 0
for i in range(len(y)):
    par = y[i]
    print('first',i)
    z[i] = x[j:par + j].sum()
    print('second',j,'par',par)
    j = j+par

>> z

0     560
1     500
2    1300
3    1440
4      60
```